# Есть ли метод создания статического веб сайта, в котором полностью отсувтсвуют расширения файлов .html в ссылках?

Tags: html, css, оптимизация-сайтов

Есть сайт компании с движком на MODx. Планирую избавиться от движка и сделать из него полностью статический сайт. Но есть проблема... Все страницы сайта уже занимают высокие позиции по СЕО оптимизации в google и yandex, поэтому нужно избавиться от расширений .html в конце ссылок. Проблем избавления в строке браузера нет, с этим все понятно, достаточно настроить файл .htaaccess, но как быть с ссылками при наведении мыши внутри самого сайта, если там будет .html на конце, то есть предположение, что google будет считать, что ссылки отличаются.

Есть ли какое-либо решение? Перечитал кучу информации, ничего на этот счет не нашел дельного, т.к. статические сайты сейчас не особо актуальны, а жаль.

Comment: Ну тут либо все ссылки в контенте везде заменять, либо со старых ссылок делать 301 редирект на новые с .html

Comment: Сделайте на php: каждую страницу поместите в директорию с соответствующим именем, все страницы назовите index.php. Тогда ссылки при наведении будут без файлового расширения. И в браузере тоже (даже не придётся шаманить с .htaccess)